# How do I render the following code in the render function?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, frontend

[This is the code for App.js (The code commented out is how the Counters component gets rendered in the code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jd7C.png)

[This is the error I'm getting when I try to render it currently, not able to render it using the class name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6OSQ.png)

[This the code for counters.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p93aI.png)

Thanks in Advance! I'm new to React and any solutions would really help me!

Comment: If you can share also Counters component code because currently I can only say you missed something with passing props.

Comment: Added the code for the counters component in the question itself.

Comment: What should be inside props.counters and in which place did you pass this ?

Comment: I don't understand? I didn't exactly write this code hence it's difficult, but is there no way I can render it?

Comment: Basically, counters is an array, all the functions are being handled inside the Counter component, and the Counters component does the same thing for multiple categories

Comment: If you can, recreate your program on Codesandbox or a similar platform and share the link. May help you find a solution.

Comment: The entire thing is present on my Github, I can share it with you.

Comment: I think it can help us to find solution